# mail() function wont work properly

Tags: php

I have to following code that works but not the way i want it

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']) && $_POST['edit']!="")
{
    // Email Information
    $firstName = $_POST['fname'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lname'];
    $mobile = $_POST['contactNumber'];
    $comments = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $_POST['email'];
    $email_to = "info@munsterweddingdjs.com";
    //$email_headers = "From: ". $firstName ." ". $lastName . " <" . $email_from . ">\r\n" . "Reply-To: info@munsterweddingdjs.com";
    $email_headers = "From: $firstName $lastName <kevin@yourwebsite.com>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: info@munsterweddingdjs.com";


    $email_subject = "Munster Wedding DJs Inquiry!";
    $email_body = "\nName: " . $firstName . " " . $lastName .
    "\nEmail: " . $email_from . 
    "\nPhone Number: " . $mobile . 
    "\nMessage: " . $comments;

    // Send Email
    $mailerResult = @mail($email_to, "$email_subject", $email_body,
    $email_headers, '-f ' . $email_from);

    // Check For Errors
    if($mailerResult) {

        //echo "Mail Sent!";
        echo '<script>document.location.href="thanks.html#anchor"</script>';
        exit();

    } else {

        //  echo "Error Sending Email!" . "<br><br>";
        //  print_r(error_get_last());
    }

}
```

If I change

```
From: $firstName $lastName <kevin@yourwebsite.com>"
```

to

```
From: $firstName $lastName <$email_from>"
```

The form doesnt send an email?
Why is this?

All i want to do is recieve the email and when i click reply it put users email address into the "to" field.

Comment: `If i change From: $firstName $lastName " to From: $firstName $lastName " `? what is the difference in both?

Comment: "From: $firstName $lastName " to From: $firstName $lastName" what do you mean? They are both the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this,
    **&lt ;** for <
    **&gt ;** for >

remove the space between **&lt** and **;**

```
$email_headers = "From: $firstName $lastName &lt; $email_from &gt;" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: info@munsterweddingdjs.com";
```

Comment: mail headers != sgml (html)